# Append text into a div with Jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I've tried the following code in my sample page and it doesn't work.All I'm trying to do is just append some text into a div on the page when the button is clicked.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script type="text/jscript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $('#testdiv').append("Hello World!!");
            });

        });

    </script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    <div id="testdiv"> 
    adiv
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Please guide me on how to get this simple thing to work in jquery...

Thanks

Edit:I updated my code as you suggested...still doesn't work...please help me...Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try fixing your script declaration from

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

as some browsers are finicky.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a handler to the button's `ready` event inside of the document's `ready` event.  Since the button is already ready by the time you add the handler, nothing happens.

You need to add a handler to the button's `click` event, like this:

```
$('#Button1').click(function () {
    $('#testdiv').append("Hello World!!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok from my tests I have found out that adding straight text to a div does not work.

for example: I will use appendTo() but it should be the same result.

My UI looks like this:

```
<body>
  <form>
      <div>

        <input id="Button1" value="Click Me!" type="button" onclick="OnBtnClick()" /> <br />
        <div id="showMeTheMoneyText"></div>
    </div>
   </form>
<body>
```

Inside my script:

```
function OnBtnClick() {

    $('Hello World!').appendTo('#showMeTheMoneyText');

    return false;
};
```

This does absolutely nothing in the UI. Why? Because you will need to wrap your text inside some HTML tag that contains the text you wish to display (i.e.

,   etc)

Look at my updated example:

```
function OnBtnClick() {

    $('<span>Hello World!</span>').appendTo('#showMeTheMoneyText');

    return false;
};
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You must use `$('#Button1').click` and not `$('#Button1').ready`